# Polymorphic lens without template haskell

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, haskell-lens

I am trying to create a polymorphic lens decleration (without template haskell) for multiple types.

```
module Sample where
import Control.Lens
data A = A {_value:: Int}
data B = B {_value:: Int}
data C = C {_value:: String}
value = lens _value (\i x -> i{_value=x}) -- <<< ERROR
```

But I get following error:

```
Ambiguous occurrence ‘_value’
It could refer to either the field ‘_value’,
                         defined at library/Sample.hs:5:13
                      or the field ‘_value’, defined at 
library/Sample.hs:4:13
                      or the field ‘_value’, defined at 
library/Sample.hs:3:13
  |
6 | value = lens _value (\i x -> i{_value=x}) -- <<< ERROR
  |              ^^^^^^
```

So, goal is to have `value` lens to work on all three types A, B and C. Is there a way to achieve that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Lenses can be derived without TH by [*generic-lens*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-lens). You can specialize the generic `field` lens to a specific field and give it a name as follows.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import Control.Lens (Lens, (^.))
import Data.Generics.Product (HasField(field))

data A = A { _value :: Int } deriving Generic
data B = B { _value :: Int } deriving Generic
data C = C { _value :: String } deriving Generic

value :: HasField "_value" s t a b => Lens s t a b
value = field @"_value"

main :: IO ()
main = print (A 0 ^. value, B 0 ^. value, C "0" ^. value)
```

Answer (score 4):

Haskell does not support overloading functions the way a language like Java or C++ does.  To do what you want you need to use a typeclass like so.

```
class HasValue a b where
    value :: Lens' a b 

data A = A {_valueA:: Int}
data B = B {_valueB:: Int}
data C = C {_valueC:: String}

instance HasValue A Int where
   value = lens _valueA (\i x -> i{_valueA=x})

instance HasValue B Int where
   value = lens _valueB (\i x -> i{_valueB=x})

instance HasValue C String where
   value = lens _valueC (\i x -> i{_valueC=x}
```

You'll need to enable multiparameter typeclasses to do this.

Comment: You probably want to make `b` functionally dependent on `a`, i.e. `{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}` `class HasValue a b | a -> b`. Or, IMO a bit preferrable, make the field type instead an associated type family:  `{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}` `class HasValue a where {type ValueField a :: *; value :: Lens' a (ValueField a)}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid `DuplicateRecordFields`, another option is to define everything in its own module, though this will require qualified imports for them to be imported into the same module.

```
module Sample.A where
import Control.Lens
data A = A {_value:: Int}
value = lens _value (\i x -> i{_value=x})

module Sample.B where
import Control.Lens
data B = B {_value:: Int}
value = lens _value (\i x -> i{_value=x})

module Sample.C where
import Control.Lens
data C = C {_value:: String}
value = lens _value (\i x -> i{_value=x})

module Main where
import qualified Sample.A as A
import qualified Sample.B as B
import qualified Sample.C as C

main :: IO ()
main = print (A.A 0 ^. A.value, B.B 0 ^. B.value, C.C "0" ^. C.value)
```